# AngularJS Factory call to PHP then back to AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Having some trouble understanding how to mix AngularJS and PHP. I am initially just trying to have an AngularJS factory make a call to a PHP file (which grabs a query), then push it back to my AngularJS factory where a Controller can use the data.

Here is what I have so far, and this gives me "undefined" when I try to `console.log` the result.

Factory

```
app.factory("PlantServiceLIVE", function($http) {
  var mData = {};
  $http.get('pages/getplants.php').success(function(data) {
    mData.data = data;
  });
  return mData;
});
```

Controller

```
app.controller('TestController', function($scope, $http, PlantServiceLIVE) {
  $scope.Plants = PlantServiceLIVE.mData;
  console.log(JSON.parse($scope.Plants));
});
```

PHP (just verified that the below works tooo)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM PlantTable";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
echo json_encode($result);
```

Not sure what exactly I am doing wrong, first time doing this.

The only developer console errors I get are `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u`, which from what I read just means the data is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not about angular but more about how Ajax requests work.

AJAX requests work asynchronously, which means that the response is not immediately available. What you need to do is to prepare your code to be notify when the response is ready.
In vanilla javascript, you'd use callback to get notified, angular uses [promises](https://www.promisejs.org/)

To get it work you need to change your code a little.
Factory

```
app.factory("PlantServiceLIVE", function($http) {
  var mData = {
    gettingPlants: function(){
      return $http.get('pages/getplants.php')
    }
  };

  return mData;
});
```

Controller

```
app.controller('TestController', function($scope, $http, PlantServiceLIVE) {
  PlantServiceLIVE.gettingPlants.then(function(response){
    console.log(JSON.parse(response.data));
  });

});
```

Comment: Hmmm, interesting! I am still getting undefined for the console.log however :/ Does my PHP return look okay?

Comment: There was a typo PlantServiceLIVE.gettingPlan -> PlantServiceLIVE.gettingPlans. I'm not a PHP guy. It would be misleading for me to say something about it. If you're using chrome/firefox, I would recommend checking out what you getting from your server.

Comment: Yup, I caught the typo before running it. And when I do the echo I am getting data back. If it stays as is, then it returns some null things, but when I actually push the result into a php array, then print it, I get all the information. (I also tried encoding the array back though too)

Comment: I think the response is not properly formatted as json. That's where the syntax error comes from

Comment: Could you please provide your server response? `then` takes two functions as parameters. success and failure callbacks. Add the second function to find out whether the request is failing.

Comment: This answer was on the right path, but I had to end up modifying it a bit with another answer I found. You helped me get there though, so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think the main problem is you're not actually calling $http.get(), you're just defining it. Also, you should read more about async calls in Angular (they're a real pain, but they get pretty cool after you get a grasp of them).

This got me started: http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/angularjs-corner-using-promises-q-handle-asynchronous-calls/ (just make sure you stay away from their official documentation; it's a real mess that's either overcomplicated or over-simplified).

Anyways, for your problem:

Try this in your factory:

```
app.factory("PlantServiceLIVE", function($http) {
  var mData = {
        get_data : function(){
            return $http.get('pages/getplants.php').success(function(data) {
                     return mData.data = data;
                   });
        }
      };

  return mData;
});
```

Then get the data (after you've received it) in your controller, like this:

```
app.controller('TestController', function($scope, $http, PlantServiceLIVE) {
  $scope.click_me = function(){
    var wait = PlantServiceLIVE.mData();
    wait.then(function(data){
      console.log(data); //you should have your data here.
      $scope.Plants = data;
    });
  }
});
```

Then make it touchable with

```
<button ng-click="click_me()">Gimme plants</button>
```

Comment: Just gave this a shot and it still returns `undefined` for console.log. :( Does my PHP return look okay?

Comment: I am also actually getting the following: `undefined is not a function`, most likely in reference to the button. But when I put an alert within the click_me, I get that alert message, so I know that it is hitting the function just fine from the button.

Comment: i forgot a "}" in the code above. Could you post the exact message you're getting in the console? (expanded and all). Also, post the entire code you're trying to get to work. Thanks.